# Key error using a readline method and Dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, methods, readline

I am trying to produce numerical values of strings based on a dictionary but whenever I try to run the program, I receive an error.

```
key error:'\n'
```

What could be the issue? I think it may be the readline method, I have 2 so that I can read each of 2 lines in testdata.txt

```
key = {'A':1,
   'B':2,
   'C':3,
   'D':4,
   'E':5,
   'F':6,
   'G':7,
   'H':8,
   'I':8,
   'J':10,
   'K':11,
   'L':12,
   'M':13,
   'N':14,
   'O':15,
   'P':16,
   'Q':17,
   'R':18,
   'S':19,
   'T':20,
   'U':21,
   'V':22,
   'W':23,
   'X':24,
   'Y':25,
   'Z':26}

infile = open("testdata.txt","r")

apro = infile.readline()
bpro = infile.readline()

aproresult = 1
bproresult = 1

for i in apro:
    aproresult *= key[i]
print(aproresult)

outfile = open("testdataAnswer.txt","w")

infile.close()
```

Below is the testdata file:

```
COMETQ
HVNGAT
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `readline()` function probably is reading in a line break, which is why you're getting `\n`. You can probably use something like `rstrip()` to strip out the trailing spaces.

```
apro = infile.readline()
bpro = infile.readline()

# Get rid of the line break using rstrip here
apro = apro.rstrip() 
bpro = bpro.rstrip()
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm somewhat new to that method so how would you implement this?

Comment: I can't really tell you how unless I know what your text file looks like. It would depend on where the `\n` is coming from.

Comment: COMETQ,
 HVNGAT     (this is the datafile, ignore this text, and the comma, the comma represents a new line )

Comment: Are those two separate lines? Is this exactly it? Are there lines in the text file? Post the exact format of the textfile in the question, that will be more helpful.

Comment: Alrighty, I have edited the question, thank you for the help btw.

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer. Update that in your code and that should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154051/discussion-between-cuber-and-victor).